# Location icon/sound keeps popping about once an hour on Amazon Fire tablet, how to make it stop?

Tags: notifications, alarm

On my Amazon Fire tablet, I've never had an issue until last week.
This icon pops up random, maybe once or twice an hour with audible sound as well. (Verso is the title of sound it makes from ringers list)

It literally makes that sound at same time as the icon appears. I hear the sound, Verso, then I look up to right top corner to see the "Arrow" icon there then it goes away in 1 second.

The icon *is* the same arrow icon for "Location" in settings.
Due to Location arrow, I've gone down the list of app permissions & turned off Location in all 18 apps using "Location". It still happens with all turned off!

Would anyone know of this and how I can stop it or at least control it?